# Can't build nextjs app for production but works well in dev (

Tags: node.js, next.js, lodash, vercel

Whenever I try to build my app for production locally or on Vercel I get this error !
I don't see the error while working locally with dev watch

This is how I build the app..

```
    "dev": "ts-node --project tsconfig.server.json server/index.ts",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "node dist/index.js",
```

The error :

```
./node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts:1025:21
Type error: Type expected.

  1023 |     type GetIndexedField<T, K> = K extends keyof T
  1024 |         ? T[K]
> 1025 |         : K extends `${number}`
       |                     ^
  1026 |             ? 'length' extends keyof T
  1027 |                 ? number extends T['length']
  1028 |                     ? number extends keyof T
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

What is wrong with this lodash module ?

Tried different versions of nodejs, it has to be v16.20.0 to match production.

Comment: Probably upgrade your typescript version. Template Literal Types are only supported since version 4.1.